# Indeterminate State of checkboxes not working in safari(Compatibility issue)

Tags: jquery, css, liferay

Indeterminate state doesnt work in Safari browser but it works in all other browsers.

The problem is with checkboxes when the checkbox is checked the child checkboxes will be displayed by jquery.When i again check the checkbox of child the indeterminate state of parent is not working in safari

This code is written for second level checkboxes. Here, im calculating the number of checkboxes(checkBoxesCount) and the number of unchecked checkboxes(uncheckedCount) in the second level.If any one of them is unchecked, its parent(first level) checkbox should go to indeterminate state. This works fine in all the browsers but not in Safari(There is no change in the state of first level checkbox if any one of the second level checkbox is unchecked, it remains in selected state only).

```
if(uncheckedCount>0 && uncheckedLength!=(checkBoxesCount-1) ){
 $('.firstLevel').prop("indeterminate", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a bug similar before, could be the way you are checking to see if a checkbox is checked or not

See this previously answered question which may help, note how the answer involves doing 2 types of checking to see if the checkbox is checked, the 2nd of which was needed to make it work on safari

Hope this helps!

[Custom checkbox not working in Chrome and Safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030636/custom-checkbox-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari-browser)